# how do I get the search bar by pressing F3 on my mac

Tags: rendering

Hi I am a beginner to blender and was watching a tutorial where the person presses the F3 command on his computer to get a search bar to access easy short cuts and other various actions. However when I press F3 on my mac it just makes my screens split.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut for macOS is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. [This Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204436) explains when and why the <kbd>Fn</kbd> is required.

> **Use standard function keys**
>
> Standard function keys work differently depending on the app and the keyboard shortcuts that you've set up. Some apps have their own keyboard shortcut preferences that you can customize.
>
> To use the standard function keys, hold the Fn (Function) key when pressing a function key. For example, pressing both Fn and F12 (speaker icon) performs the action assigned to the F12 key instead of raising the volume of your speakers.
>
> If your keyboard doesn’t have an Fn key, try pressing and holding the Control key when pressing a function key.